# jquery export selected options to text area with remove duplicates lines

Tags: jquery, export, multiple-select

I create 2 buttons, first button: to export from multiple select field to text-area, second button: to remove duplicate lines from text-area

the export button only works if I have not yet click the remove duplicates button, if I have already clicked the remove duplicates button, when i click export button again, it doesn't works again

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
    var i,
    len=arr.length,
    out=[],
    obj={};

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
    }
    for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remove-duplicates-button").click(function(){
        $("#text-area").val(eliminateDuplicates($("#text-area").val().split("\n")).join("\n"));
    });
    $("#export-button").click(function(){
        var hotels = [];
        $('#hotels :selected').each(function(i, selected){
            hotels[i] = $(selected).val()+"\n";
        });
        $("#text-area").append(hotels);
    });
});
```

need help to fix in, this is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/4dtxf/3/

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
    var i,
    len=arr.length,
    out=[],
    obj={};

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
    }
    for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remove-duplicates-button").click(function(){
        $("#text-area").val(eliminateDuplicates($("#text-area").val().split("\n")).join("\n"));
    });
    $("#export-button").click(function(){
        $("#text-area").val("");
        $('#hotels :selected').each(function(i, selected){
            $("#text-area").val($("#text-area").val() + $(selected).val()+"\n");
        });
    });
});
```

Always use `val()` to modify or get content of text area...

http://jsfiddle.net/4dtxf/14/

Comment: it's work, but other problem appear, when i input manually on text-area, and then try the button, not work again

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you had some syntax errors there, like missing `;` and commas instead of them. UPDATE: and use `val` instead of `append` to set `textarea` value.

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
    var i=0;
    var len=arr.length;
    var out=[];
    var obj={};

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
    }
    for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#remove-duplicates-button").click(function(){
        $("#text-area").val(eliminateDuplicates($("#text-area").val().split("\n")).join("\n"));
    });
    $("#export-button").click(function(){
        var hotels = [];
        $('#hotels :selected').each(function(i, selected){
            hotels[i] = $(selected).val()+"\n";
        });
        var h=hotels.toString().replace(/,/g,'');
        $("#text-area").val(h);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4dtxf/13/

Comment: click the remove duplicates button first, then click export button, its doesn't work. anybody know why?

Comment: Wait a moment, why should you? You cannot remove duplicates from an empty `textarea` - it's **empty**. You should fill it first. Your `remove-duplicates-button` works on contents of `textarea`.

Comment: Yea you are right, but then you cannot export for a second time

Comment: I prefer to use append because its purpose. thanks to both of you. solved

Comment: other problem appear T_T look at my other comment